# What configuration need to be done in my MAC 10.8.5 to act as ssl enabled ldap client for openldapserver

Tags: macos, ldap, openldap, directory-server

I configured my openldap 2.4 in Centos . And I have Mac client for it. Now i wanted to enable SSL for secured Ldap connection. I generated self certified  certificate and configured my ldap.I followed following Document http://easylinuxtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/11/installing-configuring-openldap-server.html. But in this it is centos client, but my problem is how to configure Mac client. In some google search i found that just enabling SSL option in LDAPv3 of Directory server will do the job for us. But it didnt helped me. please help me in doing some missed configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself

Firstly we should edit ldap.conf file ,which is in the path /etc/openldap/ldap.conf of client.
we should add the line

TLS_REQCERT never